# reading a fortran binary file into matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, fortran

in my fortran code i am outputting the results into a binary file.

```
      open(21,file=anum('press',itime),form=format_mode)
  write(21) rtime,itime,dt,nx0,ny0,nz,deltax,deltay,rlenz
  write(21) rw
  close(21)
```

the above is the fortran code that writes and saves the file.

i now want to open and analyse it in matlab:

```
fid = open('press.420000');
A = fread(fid);
close(fid);
```

this however, only creates a 1d array which i am guessing includes all the header information too.

i want Matlab to read the header values but not include them into the final array. i intend to reshape the array in to a 3d array as the data is from a cfd simulation which has a grid of 256x512x390 = 51,180,80

the Matlab code gives me a 1d array of 411,343,976, which cannot be correct.

thus i am struggling how to read the binary file. I need some guidance on how i should code a Matlab script to read the binary file

Comment: I recommend changing the Fortran to write a text file, and have Matlab read the text file.

Comment: If matlab does have a binary file read capability, it would be for Fortran stream files open(access='stream'...)

Comment: What is the value of `format_mode`? That is a very important information.

Comment: `format_mode` must be `unformatted` else the `write` would fail.  My advice is to use `access=stream` instead of coaxing matlab to read the arcane fortran default sequential access format.  The other concern is of course the variable types need to be the same in both programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can read data in byte vector:

```
bytevec = fread(fid, inf, 'uint8');
```

Then you can look at and manually arrange elements by their indices, for example - single precision (float) data:

```
vec = typecast(bytevec(i1:i2), 'single');
```

And then convert it to default matlab double type without changing data values:

```
vec = cast(vec, 'double');
```

Finally, you can reshape raw vector to 3d matrix:

```
M = reshape(vec, [d1, d2, d3]);
```

Comment: when i read in the file using the first line of your code... bytevec = this just imports the binary data and shows me the size in bytes, it say 411343976x1 double. i cannot view this data, so i am not sure how to use the next part of your code. plus i get an undefined variable error when using i1:i2. Also why have you suggested using uint8

Comment: the fortran code writes out the following, write(21) rtime,itime,dt,nx0,ny0,nz,deltax,deltay,rlenz, so essentially i goes i want all the values for their subsequent headings into their subsequent columns

Comment: You can view bytes from `bytevec` as unsigned integers from 0 to 255. You sholud define `i1`, `i2` variables as start and end byte positions (excluding header with fixed length, if you know binary structure of your file). It means that you should know needed byte positions. When you call `typecast`, it will reduce size of input vector by 4 (from 1-byte as uint8 to 4-byte as float).

Comment: To look variable contents, double click on it in workspace or select it from code and press Ctrl+D.